# Porque é que os números pares não têm o mesmo output que os ímpares?

Tags: java, printf

Fiz um programa que pede ao utilizador um número que vai servir de valor máximo. E de seguida o programa mostra quais os números pares e ímpares de 0 até esse número. Usei `printf` para ter um output do género:

```
Os números pares são os seguintes:
2   4   6   8  10
```

Mas no entanto tenho o seguinte output:

```
Os números pares são os seguintes:

2

4

6

8

10
```

Não percebo o porque visto que no números ímpares o output é o pretendido mas nos pares não o é. Aí fica o código que usei:

```
{
    String repetir = " " ;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Indique um valor máximo");
        int max = scanner.nextInt();
        int par= 0;
        int impar = 0;

        System . out . println("Os números pares são os seguintes:");
        while(par<= max)
        {

            if (par%2 == 0)
            {
                System . out . printf ("%3d",par); 
                System.out.println("   ");
            }
            par++;
        }
        System . out . println("Os números impares são os seguintes:");
        while (impar <= max)
        {
            if (impar %2 != 0)
            {
                System . out .printf ("%3d",impar); 
            }
            impar++;
        }
        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.println("Deseja repetir a operação?(s/n)");
        repetir = scanner.next();
    }while (repetir.equals("s"));
}
```

Comment: Qual é a diferença? O que vê de errado?

Comment: O exercício que me pede para fazer isto fala especificamente no output no entanto eu penso que usei o mesmo tipo de código para números pares como ímpares no entanto o output é outro

Comment: As respostas solucionaram seu problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só remover a linha

```
System.out.println("   ");
```

Porque você imprime uma linha vazia após cada número par

```
if (par%2 == 0)
{
    System . out . printf ("%3d",par); 
    System.out.println("   "); // <--------
}
par++;
```

E nos ímpares não

```
if (impar %2 != 0)
{
    System . out .printf ("%3d",impar); 
}
impar++;
```

Answer (score 4):

Remova essa linha:

```
System.out.println("   ");
```